# How to read csv file via handling cases like newline character in a row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, amazon-s3, codec

```
for row in codecs.getreader(self.encoding)(self.response[u'Body']).readlines():
            row_string = StringIO(row)
            print ("Row read from the data is: ")
            print (row_string.getvalue())
            df = pd.read_csv(row_string, sep=",")
```

I have written the above code to stream a csv file from S3 row by row. However, there is a row in a csv file with an *enter* in its one of the rows. Pandas is able to read it when file is downloaded in local but in the above code it is generating an error:

```
[2018-11-12 14:11:45,586] {models.py:1595} ERROR - Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at line 0
```

Ignore the line 0 remark above as you can see in my code, I read one row and form its data frame.

The complete error traceback is:

```
[2018-11-12 14:11:45,586]



{models.py:1595} ERROR - Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside
 string starting at line 0 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
 "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1493,
 in _run_raw_task
     result = task_copy.execute(context=context)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py",
 line 89, in execute
     return_value = self.execute_callable()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py",
 line 94, in execute_callable
     return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)   File
 "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pallet-0.0.0-py3.5.egg/pallet/tasks/versionator.py", line 228, in driver_de_versionator
     a.index_patch()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pallet-0.0.0-py3.5.egg/pallet/tasks/versionator.py", line 202, in index_patch
     DB.process(self.form_candidate_version, self.destination_of_kch_file_to_be_downloaded)   File
 "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pallet-0.0.0-py3.5.egg/pallet/tasks/versionator.py", line 144, in form_candidate_version
     df = pd.read_csv(row_string, sep=",")   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line
 678, in parser_f
     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line
 440, in _read
     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line
 787, in __init__
     self._make_engine(self.engine)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line
 1014, in _make_engine
     self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line
 1708, in __init__
     self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)   File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 539, in
 pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__   File
 "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 737, in
 pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header   File
 "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 932, in
 pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows   File
 "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 2112, in
 pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error pandas.errors.ParserError:
 Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at line 0
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick google of your woe turns up [this link](https://www.shanelynn.ie/pandas-csv-error-error-tokenizing-data-c-error-eof-inside-string-starting-at-line/), which suggests:

> The solution was to use the parameter `engine='python'` in the `read_csv`
>   function call. The Pandas CSV parser can use two different “engines”
>   to parse CSV file – Python or C (default).

```
pandas.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep=', ', delimiter=None, 
                header='infer', names=None, 
                index_col=None, usecols=None, squeeze=False, 
                ..., engine=None, ...)
```

> ***engine*** : {'c', 'python'}, optional
>
> Parser engine to use. The C engine is faster while the python engine
>   is currently more feature-complete.

Comment: No no
My code has a for loop which uses readlines(). This is giving pandas an incomplete row:  `print (row_string.getvalue())` validated this statement. 

Hence, if row_string variable itself is messed up, what can Pandas improvement (as you suggested) can do?!

Comment: Interesting, from your code it looked like each row itself is a csv `df` that you want to read since for each row you are creating a `df`.  If that's not the case, what's the issue with just reading the entire data as a csv into one cohesive `df`?

Comment: My objective is to stream the csv file from S3. 
Here, I am streaming one row and forming a dataframe.
Can you suggest a better method? Or even your method, as to how to implement it?